# WPF TreeView Arrange Max Size

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I have a TreeView inside of a Canvas.  When a TreeViewItem is collapsed, the TreeView shrinks.    I can explicitly set the Height and Width, but it may vary as the number of items change.  I want the TreeView to always be as big as possible.  In other words, I want the TreeView to size itself as if every TreeViewItem was expanded.

Here is what I attempted when extending the TreeView, but it doesn't quite work.

```
protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds)
    {
        if (this.ActualHeight > arrangeBounds.Height)
        {
            arrangeBounds.Height = this.ActualHeight;
        }
        if (this.ActualWidth > arrangeBounds.Width)
        {
            arrangeBounds.Width = this.ActualWidth;
        }
        return base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeBounds);
    }
```

Edit:

I need the treeview in a canvas so I can pan and zoom around properly.

Here are a couple screen shots.

[image]

Notice how the treeview isn't staying the max size??  It's shrinking to the required size.  But the horizontal alignment is working as if the treeview is still large.
[image]

If I remove my ArrangeOverride, the items are visible, but the treeview is shrinking.
[image]

Comment: can you add images of your current UI ?

Comment: Not sure why you would need to embed it in a canvas, but ya could you provide something to visualize what you're after vs what you have?

Comment: The only idea I came up with is to maintain another TreeView with its visibility set to Hidden and call ExpandSubTree() on its Items when ever one is added. Then bind Width and Height of the visible TreeView to ActualWidth and ActualHeight of the invisible one.

Comment: That idea is not bad @chickenpie.  I'll give it a try.  Unless someone questions why.  Then it may die.

Comment: That did the trick for now @chickenpie.